# Permission analysis of APK

Tags: apk, android-permissions

Have anyone tried to use this extension of Androguard and MobSF ?
This is the Github link: https://github.com/chushu10/apk-static-features-extraction

I cannot find the file mass_static_analysis.py of Androguard, and I want to run the file in the extension of MobSF. Can anyone help?